# Calling super view function from sub view

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uitextfield, warnings

I have a UIView called **Product**, which contains a sub UIView called **Postcode**.

In the Postcode `UIView` i have a simple form (one `UITextField` and one `UIButton`).

When the `UIButton` is clicked a method (called `-storeData`) is run inside postcode view ... which works as intended.

Now inside `storeData` I would like to call a method in the superview Product.

This is what i tried doing, but im getting a warning:

```
if ([[self superview] class] == [ProductView class]) {
        ProductView *p = [self superview]; 
        [p handlePostChange]; 
    }
```

// Get this warning from this line `ProductView *p = [self superview];`

> PostView.m:124:28: Incompatible pointer types initializing
>   'ProductView *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIView *'

Comment: Superclasses are not aware of subclasses.

Comment: yep.. but im doing this check in the sub class...

Comment: Yes, but that still doesn't make the superclass aware of the subclass.  You're not editing the superclass, are you?

Comment: so this is what is happening... button clicked in sub class -> function run in sub class -> inside this function, another function is called in the superclass-> this function updates a label in the super class uiview

Comment: I think what you are trying to do would be better done by making the Superview a delegate of the sub view through the help of a protocol implemented by the super view.

Comment: As an aside, you generally check class membership with [`isKindOfClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:) or [`isMemberOfClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCEBEIC).

Comment: oo that sounds like a good solution Peter... how can i make the super view a delegate of the subview?

Comment: @ParampalP See my answer that I just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `[self superview]` returns a `UIView` pointer. You are trying to do the equivalent of:

```
UIView *view;
ProductView *p = view;
```

The compiler has no way to know that at runtime, `view` will really be of type `ProductView`. This is why the compiler complains.

The solution, as was stated, is to use a cast:

```
UIView *view;
ProductView *p = (ProductView *)view;
```

The cast tells the compiler "hey, don't worry, I know what I'm doing. It really is a `ProductView`". Of course if you are wrong, the app will most likely crash at runtime.

The following is perfectly fine:

```
ProductView *p;
UIView *view = p;
```

This is safe, gives no warning, and requires no cast. This works because it is known that `ProductView` is a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: yep cool thanks... to avoid it crashing at runtime, i double check to see that the super class is of ProductView type. ie. `if ([[self superview] class] == [ProductView class]) {`

Comment: Yes, and that's very good. I was making a general statement. Since you do a proper runtime check, you are safe.

Answer (score 3):

Try just casting the result:

```
ProductView *p = (ProductView *)[self superview];
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment you *may* be better off using a delegation pattern.

I know it is a lot more code than simply checking the class type of the parent, but it gains you a lot more capability as it decouples the `Product` and `Postcode` classes.  Thus the class that implements the `handlePostChangeFor:` method no longer has to be `Product` - it can be any class as long as it implements the `SuperProtocol`.  Which in turn means you never have to check the class type inside `Postocde`, as you no longer care about it - all you care about is that some other class can do the work you want. Also if the `superHandlerDelegate` property in the instance of a `Postcode` is never set and remains `nil` you are still OK as Objective-c allows messages to be sent to `nil`.

Note that the code below is done in very broad brushstrokes and I have left a lot of extraneous stuff out.  One main difference between your code and this example is that you now have to carry a parameter in the `handlePostChangeFor:` method to indicate which Postcode you are handling the change for.  This is a direct result of having decoupled the two classes.

```
// Declare a protocol saying "Here is some functionality"
@protocol SuperProtocol
-(void) handlePostChangeFor:(Postcode*)postcode;
@end

// Product class says it will implement the functionality of the SuperProtocol
@interface Product : UIView <SuperProtocol>
@end

@implmementation Product
-(id)init
{
   if (!(self=[super init])) return self;
   ...
   // Create/locate the Postcode that is a child of this Product
   Postcode* postcode = ... // For example :- [[Postcode alloc] init];

   // Tell an instance of the Postcode class who will be supplying the SuperProtocol functionality
   postcode.superHandlerDelegate = self;
   ...
   return self;
}

// Implement the protocol's functionality
-(void) handlePostChangeFor:(Postcode*)postcode
{
  // Do Stuff with the data from the postcode instance
}
@end


@interface Postcode : UIView
// Identify who will implement the SuperProtocol functionality for this instance
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <SuperProtocol> superHandlerDelegate;
-(IBAction)storeData:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation Postcode
@synthesize superHandlerDelegate;
-(id)init
{
   if (!(self=[super init])) return self;
   ...
   // This is not required as NSObject's `alloc` sets everything to all zeroes
   // Note that you should not use "self.xxxxx" in an init method
   superHandlerDelegate = nil;
   ...
   return self;
}

-(IBAction)storeData:(id)sender
{
    ...
    // Tell the delegate to do the work
    [self.superHandlerDelegate handlePostChangeFor:self];
    ...
}

@end
```